# Where to find "syntax highlighter" scope syntax for Sublime Text 3?

Tags: scope, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I am writing a syntax highlighter for Sublime Text 3, but I am facing problem of find the correct scope for syntax.
For example

```yaml
  constants:
    - match: \b(true|false)\b
      scope: constants.language.boolean
    - match: \b(void|new)\b
      scope: constants.language

# operators
  operators:
    - match: \b(and|or|not)\b
      scope: keyword.operator.logical
    - match: \b(\+=|-=|*=|\/=|%=|==|!=|<=|>=|<|>|\+|-|\*|\/|%|\^)\b
      scope: keyword.operator.arithmetic
```

How do I know scope of `and`, `+=`, `true`, `false` etc.

Where are all the available scope syntax present?

Can anyone direct me to it's documentation/source code? Any help will be appreciated.
I found this official page on syntax highlighting https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html, but it didn't help much.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read through the existing `.sublime-syntax` files, located on Github at [`sublimehq/Packages`](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages), for the standards that are being used. I'd also suggest using the [**`ScopeHunter`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter) and [**`ScopeAlways`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeAlways) plugins when viewing files in other languages to determine which scopes are active at a given point.

Here are some other resources:

- [Sublime Text unofficial docs on syntax definitions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html)
- [Unofficial docs syntax definitions reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html)
- [TextMate Manual on naming conventions](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars) - scroll down to section 12.4

There are no hard-and-fast "standards" as such, but trying to follow the TextMate conventions is a good idea. If the language you're writing the definition for is similar to an existing language, you can also use that as a template. However, every definition is slightly different, so don't be afraid to make up your own unique selectors if necessary.

Comment: I did read through existing `.sublime-syntax` but it's like doing things by trial and error in undocumented way.

Comment: @igaurav see my additions above.